# Mongodb, NodeJs and Mongoose: Get inner object where inner Object value='search value'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Example first:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f086809bf28fd7bb56e6059"), "admins" : [ "4ef8e785b2694c3649000001" ], "pages" : [
    {
        "pagename" : "home",
        "title" : "homepage",
        "default" : true
    },
    {
        "pagename" : "people",
        "title" : "Staff",
        "default" : false
    }
], "sitename" : "Site", "sitenameLower" : "site" }
```

So that's the document I'm querying, now what I want is to return the 'page' where pagename = 'home'.

I've tried various queries but it always returns the whole document and not the individual object inside the pages array - which is not much use to me.

Including:

```
db.sites.find({'pages.pagename' : 'home'});
```

I can see, why this is wrong, but getting it right, is perplexing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268568/mongodb-query-to-return-only-embedded-document). Looks like it's a [planned feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) but you can't do it right now.

Comment: Thanks, ok I'll just refactor it, into another collection of pages.
I've actually been thinking about how I do subsites and pages, so I may need to refactor it anyway... so that I have a collection of site items, namely pages, subsites, other lists.